Problema creando una base de datos desde Odoo
Estoy intentando crear una BBDD en odoo y me sale el siguiente error:
Database creation error: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 85: invalid continuation byte
He cambiado la configuración de encoding de los usuarios pero sigue sin funcionar, pongo el logfile por si me pueden ayudar:
2024-10-16 08:39:01,528 5632 INFO None odoo.service.db: Create database `DemoDB`. 
2024-10-16 08:39:01,575 5632 ERROR None odoo.addons.web.controllers.database: Database creation error. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\odoo\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\database.py", line 81, in create
    dispatch_rpc('db', 'create_database', [master_pwd, name, bool(post.get('demo')), lang, password, post['login'], country_code, post['phone']])
  File "C:\Program Files\odoo\server\odoo\http.py", line 391, in dispatch_rpc
    return dispatch(method, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\odoo\server\odoo\service\db.py", line 488, in dispatch
    return g[exp_method_name](*params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\odoo\python\Lib\site-packages\decorator.py", line 232, in fun
    return caller(func, *(extras + args), **kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\odoo\server\odoo\service\db.py", line 43, in if_db_mgt_enabled
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\odoo\server\odoo\service\db.py", line 148, in exp_create_database
    _create_empty_database(db_name)
  File "C:\Program Files\odoo\server\odoo\service\db.py", line 101, in _create_empty_database
    with closing(db.cursor()) as cr:
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\odoo\server\odoo\sql_db.py", line 753, in cursor
    return Cursor(self.__pool, self.__dbname, self.__dsn)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\odoo\server\odoo\sql_db.py", line 267, in __init__
    self._cnx = pool.borrow(dsn)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\odoo\python\Lib\site-packages\decorator.py", line 232, in fun
    return caller(func, *(extras + args), **kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\odoo\server\odoo\tools\func.py", line 87, in locked
    return func(inst, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\odoo\server\odoo\sql_db.py", line 682, in borrow
    result = psycopg2.connect(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\odoo\python\Lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 85: invalid continuation byte
2024-10-16 08:39:02,564 5632 INFO None werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2024 08:39:02] "POST /web/database/create HTTP/1.1" 200 - 3 0.000 2.827
2024-10-16 08:39:03,595 5632 INFO Postgres werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2024 08:39:03] "GET /web/service-worker.js HTTP/1.1" 200 - 1 0.000 0.004
2024-10-16 08:39:18,881 5632 WARNING DemoDB odoo.addons.base.models.ir_cron: Exception in cron: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\odoo\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_cron.py", line 119, in _process_jobs
    with db.cursor() as cron_cr:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\odoo\server\odoo\sql_db.py", line 753, in cursor
    return Cursor(self.__pool, self.__dbname, self.__dsn)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\odoo\server\odoo\sql_db.py", line 267, in __init__
    self._cnx = pool.borrow(dsn)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\odoo\python\Lib\site-packages\decorator.py", line 232, in fun
    return caller(func, *(extras + args), **kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\odoo\server\odoo\tools\func.py", line 87, in locked
    return func(inst, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\odoo\server\odoo\sql_db.py", line 682, in borrow
    result = psycopg2.connect(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\odoo\python\Lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 85: invalid continuation byte
2024-10-16 08:39:18,924 5632 WARNING Demo odoo.addons.base.models.ir_cron: Exception in cron: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\odoo\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_cron.py", line 119, in _process_jobs
    with db.cursor() as cron_cr:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\odoo\server\odoo\sql_db.py", line 753, in cursor
    return Cursor(self.__pool, self.__dbname, self.__dsn)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\odoo\server\odoo\sql_db.py", line 267, in __init__
    self._cnx = pool.borrow(dsn)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\odoo\python\Lib\site-packages\decorator.py", line 232, in fun
    return caller(func, *(extras + args), **kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\odoo\server\odoo\tools\func.py", line 87, in locked
    return func(inst, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\odoo\server\odoo\sql_db.py", line 682, in borrow
    result = psycopg2.connect(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\odoo\python\Lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 85: invalid continuation byte


Revisa que la db esté configurada para usar UTF-8 como codificación predeterminada, tambien revisa que la bd soporte todas las localizaciones si quieres validar que la db soporta UTF-8 predeterminado lo puedes validar asi:
SHOW SERVER_ENCODING;
